# Firebase Crashlytics doesn't report crashes from release build in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase Crashlytics doesn't report crashes from Release build in Android Studio App.

I setup using this:

```
val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId("---")
            .setApplicationId("---")
            .setApiKey("---")
            .build()
        try {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "---")
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
            Log.i("crashlytics","Connected Prd")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.i("crashlytics","Not connected: $e")
        }
```

And it works for Debug build, so the plugins are being implemented correctly, I don't know what to do